# Помогите разобраться с gulp

Tags: gulp-sass

я начал изучать фронтэнд, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, решил освоить GULP хоть и многие говорят что он устарел и не актуален но всё же, проблема состоит в том что при таске у меня в папке fonts хранится файл fonts.scss, мне нужно что бы данный файл не дублировался в конечном каталоге public/fonts/

// fonts copy
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
return gulp
.src('./src/fonts/**/*')
.pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts/'))
});

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.